# Kafka and apache Spark streaming cluster configuration

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I need to run some Spark scala scripts on a cluster of machines. Data are generated by an Apache Kafka producer running on 1 of these machines.

I have already configured the slaves.template file in the conf directory in Apache Spark with the URL of every node of the cluster.

I run the scripts with this instruction:
`./bin/spark-submit --class com.unimi.lucaf.App /Users/lucaferrari/scala-spark-script2/target/scala-spark-script-1.0.jar` but it seemes that it is only running on the master node.

How can i fix it?

Thanks

**SOLVED**

1. In folder `conf` renamed the `slaves.template` file to `slaves` and added the URL of every worker
2. In folder `conf` renamed the `spark-env.sh.template`file to `spark-env.sh` and added these lines:

   `SPARK_MASTER_HOST=1.2.3.4`

   `SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077`

   `SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=4444`

   `SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT=8081`
3. In folder `sbin` on the master machine I run the `start-master.sh` script.
4. On every worker, in folder `sbin` I run `start-slave.sh spark://master-url:master-port`. `master-url` and `master-port` must be the same configured in the `spark-env.sh` file.
5. On the spark configuration of the script I've added also the master-url (`val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkScript").setMaster("spark://master-url:master-port")`
6. Run the script with `./bin/spark-submit --class com.unimi.lucaf.App /home/spark1/scala-spark-script2/target/scala-spark-script-1.0.jar --master spark://master-url:master-port --deploy-mode cluster`

Comment: Have you used `deploy-mode` ? Please share how is your spark cluster prepared? What version of spark is used and more information.

You can also check
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add the

```
--master <master_url>
```

option? If you omit this option to spark-submit, it will run locally.

You may also check Spark's documentation on spark-submit options: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit